ReactJs component deletes instead of editing
I think perhaps my approach for creating this kind of component, might be completely incorrect.
I want to create a sort of tab which will open and close when the arrow is clicked and keep it editable at the same time. I want to have the component not delete itself unless there is no content inside.
What happens with this though, is the component when editing just deletes.
Parent Component
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";
import { useEdgeStore } from "@/lib/edgestore";
import { BlockNoteEditor, BlockNoteSchema, defaultBlockSpecs, filterSuggestionItems, insertOrUpdateBlock } from "@blocknote/core";
import { BlockNoteView, SuggestionMenuController, getDefaultReactSlashMenuItems,  useCreateBlockNote,} from "@blocknote/react";
import "@blocknote/react/style.css";
import { RiArrowRightFill } from 'react-icons/ri';
import { ParagraphToggle } from './paragraph-toggle/paragraph-toggle';


const schema = BlockNoteSchema.create({
  blockSpecs: {
    // Adds all default blocks.
    ...defaultBlockSpecs,
    toggle: ParagraphToggle,
  },
});

interface EditorProps {
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
  initialContent?: string;
  editable?: boolean;
}

const insertToggle = (editor: typeof schema.BlockNoteEditor) => ({
  title: 'Toggle-Paragraph',
  onItemClick: () => {
    insertOrUpdateBlock(editor, {
      type: 'toggle',
      props: {
        title: 'Toggle Paragraph Title',
        isOpen: false,
      },
    });
  },
  aliases: ['toggle', 'dropdown'],
  group: 'Headings',
  icon: <RiArrowRightFill />,
});



const Editor = ({ onChange, initialContent, editable }: EditorProps) => {
  const { resolvedTheme } = useTheme();
  const { edgestore } = useEdgeStore();

  const handleUpload = async (file: File) => {
    const response = await edgestore.publicFiles.upload({ file });
    return response.url;
  };

  const editor = useCreateBlockNote({
    schema,
    initialContent: initialContent ? JSON.parse(initialContent) : undefined,
    uploadFile: handleUpload
  });


  return(
  <BlockNoteView editor={editor} slashMenu={false} theme={resolvedTheme === "dark" ? "dark" : "light"}>
      {/* Replaces the default Slash Menu. */}
      <SuggestionMenuController
        triggerCharacter={'/'}
        getItems={async (query) =>
          filterSuggestionItems(
            [
              ...getDefaultReactSlashMenuItems(editor),
              /**Add here new components for menu */

              insertToggle(editor),
            ],
            query
          )
        }
      />
    </BlockNoteView>
  );
};


export default Editor;

Child component:
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { defaultProps } from '@blocknote/core';
import { createReactBlockSpec } from '@blocknote/react';

export const ParagraphToggle = createReactBlockSpec(
  {
    type: 'toggle',
    propSchema: {
      textAlignment: defaultProps.textAlignment,
      textColor: defaultProps.textColor,
      isOpen: {
        default: false,
        values: [true, false],
      },
      title: {
        default: 'Toggle Title',
        values: [],
      },
    },
    content: 'inline',
  },
  {
    render: (props) => {
      return (
        <details contentEditable="true">
          <pre></pre>
          <summary>Edit Summary</summary>
          <p>Edit Details</p>
        </details>
      );
    },
  }
);




export default ParagraphToggle;

Here is an image of what I am trying to acheive.

